# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in ParseExact

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

When I try to convert the `DateTime` to a specific format i'm getting this error.

```
DateTime.Now= 6/5/2013 2:29:21 PM

DateTime.ParseExact(CStr(DateTime.Now), "MM/dd/yyyy",  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

Why i'm getting this?

Comment: Which culture is this? Try examining `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and seeing what it says.

Comment: Rhetorical question: is the first argument in the same **exact** format as your format string? Did you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)?

Comment: Also, *why* are you doing this? Why not just `DateTime.Today`? It doesn't make much sense to take a `DateTime`, convert it to a string, and then parsing it back to a `DateTime`.

Comment: I need to validate the `datetime` format so i'm trying in this way. The format is provided by the user and I have to validate it

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Same error after using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`

Comment: See if [this helps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx).

Comment: @Jon: The first argument is a string correct?

Comment: @Sandy: I wanted to know which culture this was, not just that *you* had looked at it. I wanted to try to reproduce the problem but I need your culture.

Comment: @Sandy: The first argument contains time information. The specified format does not mention time information. Therefore ParseExact throws because the input does not match the format. What is surprising?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: "en-US"

Comment: @Jon: But I need to make sure that the given format is correct. Now that's correct right? So it has to convert the datetime to Date.

Comment: @Jon: So you say that if the format is given as "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" will be ok? correct?

Comment: @Sandy: No. I say "read the documentation".

Comment: @Jon: The answer is below. That is what I want.

Comment: @Sandy: You can either learn how to find the answer yourself (it was extremely easy in this case) or depend on others to provide it. Your choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you're converting a DateTime to a string then back again, the DateTime format doesn't match exactly.

`DateTime.ParseExact` parses a string into a DateTime object, and the format you provide it must match *exactly*. You said that `DateTime.Now` appears as `6/5/2013 2:29:21 PM`, for which the correct format is `M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt`. Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more information on custom date formats.

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that, by looking at your code, I think you are trying to format the date into just the date, which can be achieved using the `ToString` method on DateTime:

```
string todaysDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); // todaysDate will contain "06/05/2013"
```

Comment: I should have used this. Thanks. But this is not known to many people here.

Comment: But why this doesn't throw exception? DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dddd/yyyy");

Comment: Ok so maybe I didn't understand what you are trying to do. `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.ParseExact` are for turning strings into DateTime objects. `DateTime.ToString` is for turning a DateTime into a string representation. I've read the comments on your question and it seems you want to validate a date/time format provided by the user, is that correct?

Comment: @Sandy Perhaps you could provide an example of some user inputs, tell us what those inputs represent and some examples of what you want to finish with.

Comment: S correct. I have to validate the user given date/datetime format.

Comment: @Sandy Ok well I'm not sure you can achieve that using DateTime parsing. The only way you can check that a Date/Time format is valid is by checking that the format doesn't contain any characters that aren't valid as format specifiers. Technically, any format the user enters is valid because any characters not recognised as format specifiers will simply be output in the string as they were, e.g. `DateTime.Now.ToString("CC/dd/yyyy")` will output `CC/05/2013`. Do you see what I am saying?

Comment: @Sandy Additionally, `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dddd/yyyy")` will not fail, it will simply output `06/Wednesday/2013`. This is expected and is defined in the MSDN documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ddddSpecifier

Answer (score 2):

`6/5/2013 2:29:21 PM` is not the same as `MM/dd/yyyy`.
So of course the parse fails.

From your comments it sounds like you are really testing the format string, and you don't care about the value of the date.
So why not just hard code your date in the format you really want:

```
String userInput = "MM/dd/yyyy";
DateTime.ParseExact("11/11/2011", userInput,  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the part of the method named *Exact*, you're giving it a string containing a time, and does not specify how to parse the time, so the parsing will fail.

Try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(str, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Example [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program:

```
void Main()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

    string str = "6/5/2013 2:29:21 PM";

    DateTime.ParseExact(str, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Dump();
}
```

Output:

```
6/5/2013 2:29:21 PM
```